# vue-router details not defined

Tags: json, api, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Click here for more Details button but it doesn't load the Details.vue on the click so it doesn't show more information on the page. But I get this error Property or method "Details" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

ArticleListItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card-body"> 
    <h6 class="card-text">{{ result.title }}</h6>
      <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"
      >{{ result.publisher }} | {{ result.journal }} | {{ result.year }}</p>
      <a :href="'https://test.org/api/articles?docid=' + result._gddid" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-download"  alt="Download"> </i>
      </a>
        <router-link dark :to="{name: 'Details', params: {id: result._gddid}}">
              Click here for more Details
        </router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ArticleListItem',
  props: ['result'],  
}
</script>
```

Details.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="Details">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" v-for="result in results" :key="result._gddid"> 
                    <div v-if="id == result._gddid">
                        <h1>{{results.title}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</template>
<script>
 export default {
  name: 'Details',
  computed: { results(){ return this.$parent.$data.results } }
  
};
</script>
```

main.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue' import App from './App.vue' import VueRouter from 'vue-router'; import moment from 'moment'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return moment(value.toString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Details from './components/Details';

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
     path: '/Details/:id',
     name: 'Details',
     component: Details
   }
 ]
})


new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters on click to view more details using vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040826/passing-parameters-on-click-to-view-more-details-using-vue-js)

Comment: no that is my question and no one answered it @KrzysztofKaczyński